# PHP password_verify not working against database

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection, php-password-hash

I'm trying to me a page more secure and I started with the password encrypting part of it. I'm trying to implement password_hash + password verify, but so far I've been unsuccessful to make the whole thing work. So, here it is in my login area:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT username, password FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and user_enabled='1'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $dbpassword = $row['password']; }

if(password_verify($password, $dbpassword)) {
    echo "Successful login";
}else{
    echo "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
```

I always get Invalid Login Credentials.

When I modify the new password for the user, I am doing the following:

```
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
$options = [ 'cost' => 10,
             'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
           ];
$password = password_hash($pass,  PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";

$query = "UPDATE users 
          SET `password` = '".$password."'
          WHERE id = ".$_POST['user_id']."
          ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

password in database is VARCHAR(255), and it is storing something like:

```
$2y$10$Y5HIyAsLMfkXIFSJONPsfO3Gxx3b46H.8/WFdLVH3Fqk2XNfy2Uaq
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Debug every step of the way; `var_dump($password)` right after hashing, check it in your database, check it after you've pulled it out of the database. Does it change at all at any stage…? Do the same with the password you're trying to verify.

Comment: And learn to use prepared statements and bound parameters instead of SQL-injection-prone string concatenation.

Comment: I just confirmed that the password created before updating the database is the same than the one stored into the database, and it's the same pulled from the database at the time of login.

Comment: Prepared statements and bound parameters will be the next step. I started with this part first... step by step

Comment: Use placeholder values. This fixes a *lot* of problems before they waste your time. It's one more line of code, and a lot less typing of repetitive garbage manual escaping.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\n` in the following line, is embedding a linebreak, *(Edit: one that cannot be included in the user inputted password)*.

```
$password = password_hash($pass,  PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
```

and you need to delete it and start over with a new hash.

[Jay Blanchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard), a member here on Stack [submitted a note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017) about it not too long also in the  [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) manual, which is something that he and I actually talked about.

> *Be care when using the example from the documentation which concatenates a newline character `\n` to the end of the hash, i.e.:*
>
> *`echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";`*
>
> *People are storing the hash with the concatenated newline and consequently `password_verify()` will fail.*

Another option would be to use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php); that also works (at the moment of hashing).

```
$password = password_hash($pass,  PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)."\n";
$password = trim($password);
// Store in db after
```

Yet you still need to start over by clearing the old hash(es) and creating new ones.

Do keep in mind though, that you shouldn't escape passwords.

One such as `123'\abc` (being perfectly valid) will be modified to `123\'\abc` by [`real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php); it's not needed. [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) takes care of that, security-wise.

Comment: Wow, right on the coin! I never saw that comment. Thank you very much @Fred -ii-

Comment: @cbarg You're welcome. Jay submitted that note not too long ago. He and I talked about submitting a note, and so he went ahead and did it, which is something that is often overlooked. It would help if you could upvote [Jay's note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#121017) in the manual for it http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php - That note was long overdue and hopefully others will read the user contributed notes. *Cheers*

Comment: If it's just adding a newline, `REPLACE()` in the database should be able to fix it. The hash itself is correct.

Comment: @tadman It's not "adding" a new line *per se*, it's embedding the (invisible) `\n` in the (saved) hash.

Comment: Right, I mean it's in the field appended after the hash, so you can strip it off. It's part of the saved value, it's not something that *was* incorporated into the hash itself.

Comment: @tadman Sure, it can be stripped with `trim()` at the time of inserting/updating the row. Yet TBH; I don't know how to do this with `REPLACE()`. Edit: I don't think that function can find and replace an invisible character.

Comment: You can always use [hex literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) if you're having trouble otherwise.